# bottom navigationbar is not responding (unclickable)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

the buildAuthscreen function is not responding the NavigationBar not click or switching pages
and the it enter in while loop .

So I'd like to ask all of you, maybe someone will be able to explain to me why I get that error, what does it mean, and how to get rid of it.

any answers for this problem ?
and,thanks

```dart
import 'package:MeeM/add/add.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/CreateAccount.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/Home.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/notification.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/search.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/user.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/profileUI/profile.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/nav.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/newNav.dart';

final GoogleSignIn googlesignin = GoogleSignIn();
final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
final postRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');
final commentsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('comments');
final activityFeedRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('feed');
final followersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('followers');
final followingRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('following');
final homeRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Home');
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
final DateTime createdTime = DateTime.now();

User currentUser;

class signup_page extends StatefulWidget {
  const signup_page({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _signup_pageState createState() => _signup_pageState();
}

class _signup_pageState extends State<signup_page> {
  bool isAuth = true;
  PageController pageController;
  int pageindex = 0;

  login() {
    googlesignin.signIn();
  }

  logout() {
    googlesignin.signOut();
  }

  void onPageChanged(int pageindex) {
    setState(() {
      this.pageindex = pageindex;
    });
  }

  onTap(int pageindex) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      pageindex,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  void inistate() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
    //detects when our user signed in
    googlesignin.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {
      HandleSignIn(account);
    }, onError: (error) {
      print('Error sign in :$error');
    });
    //reauthanticate user when app is opened or reopened
    googlesignin.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
      HandleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Error sign in:$error');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  HandleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) async {
    if (account != null) {
      await createUserFireStoreData();
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
      });
    }
  }

  createUserFireStoreData() async {
    // 1) this lines are used to find if the user exist or not in the Database
    //(according to their ID)
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googlesignin.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.doc(user.id).get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      //2)this lines are used to check if the user doesn't exist , then we want  to take them to
      //create account page
      final username = await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));
      //3)and last get usersnames form creat account , use it to make new users  document
      //in users collection
      userRef.doc(user.id).set({
        'id': user.id,
        'username': username,
        'photoUrl': user.photoUrl,
        'email': user.email,
        'DisplayName': user.displayName,
        'bio': '',
        'CreatedTime': createdTime,
      });
      // make new user their own folllower (to include their post in their home page)
      await followersRef
          .doc(user.id)
          .collection('userFollowers')
          .doc(user.id)
          .set({});
      doc = await userRef.doc(user.id).get();
    }

    currentUser = User.fromDocument(doc);
    print(currentUser);
    print(currentUser.username);
  }

  Scaffold buildAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Home(currentUser: currentUser),
          search(),
          add(currentUser: currentUser),
          notification(),
          profile(profileId: currentUser?.id),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        currentIndex: pageindex,
        onTap: (index) => pageindex = index,
        activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_box_outlined),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Scaffold buidlUnAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Colors.purpleAccent,
              Colors.lightBlue[200],
            ],
          ),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'MeeM',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 80,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => login(),
              child: Container(
                width: 260.0,
                height: 60.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/google_signin_flat.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth ? buildAuthScreen() : buidlUnAuthScreen();
  }
}
~~~!
```

Comment: just a quick FYI: Don't use variables outside your class scope. You're making them global and that's not how Flutter works or should work. Classes also follow CamelCase format and lastly, you need to update your state when you tap on a new tab, if not, the UI will never be notified.

Comment: continue from my previous one: onTap: (index) => pageindex = index, is updating the value but not the UI. If you don't do "setState" and inside that method updating that value, nothing will ever happen.

Comment: can you  answer the question  please by show m the changes that i should do or function i should add